# Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'title' of 'list' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, axios

I am using axios to get the data in my mongoDB database and I want to use in my code to display information in my react front end but My react front is blank and i am getting and error that says
'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'title' of 'list' as it is undefined.'

here is the home page code:

```
import './Home.scss'
import Navbar from '../../components/Navbar/Navbar'
import Featured from '../../components/Featured/Featured'
import List from '../../components/List/List'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from '../../axios'

function Home({ type }) {
 const [lists, setLists] = useState([]);
 const [genre, setGenre] = useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {
  const getRandomLists = async () =>{
   try {
     const response = await axios.get(
      `lists`,
      ,{
        headers: {
          token: "Bearer //my jwt token"
         },
        }
       );
      console.log(response)
      setLists(response.data)

    } catch (err) {
     console.log(err)
   }
};

 getRandomLists();
 }, [type, genre])

 return (
   <div className='home'>
     <Navbar />
     <Featured type={type}/>
      {lists.map((list) => (
       <List list={list}/>
      ))}
  </div>
  )
  }

  export default Home
```

and here is my List page code:

```
import './List.scss'
import ArrowBackIosIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowBackIos';
import ArrowForwardIosIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowForwardIos';
import ListItem from '../ListItem/ListItem';
import { useRef, useState } from 'react';

function List({list}) {
 const {title, content} = list
 const [isMoved, setIsMoved] = useState(false)
 const [slideNumber, setSlideNumber] = useState(0)
 const listRef = useRef()

 const handleClick = (direction) => {
    setIsMoved(true  )
    let distance = listRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().x - 50
    if(direction === 'left' && slideNumber > 0){
         setSlideNumber(slideNumber - 1)
        listRef.current.style.transform = `translateX(${230 + distance }px)`
    }
    if(direction === 'right' && slideNumber < 4){
        setSlideNumber(slideNumber +1)
        listRef.current.style.transform = `translateX(${-230 + distance }px)`
    }
  }

 return (
 <div className='list'>
    <span className="listTitle">{}</span>
    <div className="wrapper">
        <ArrowBackIosIcon 
            className='sliderArrow left' 
            onClick={() => handleClick('left')}
            style={{display : !isMoved && 'none' }}
            />
        <div className="container" ref={listRef}>
            {

            }
        </div>
        <ArrowForwardIosIcon className='sliderArrow right' onClick={() => 
         handleClick('right')}/>
     </div>
    </div>
    )
    }

   export default List
```

I have tried all i know I don't know why am still getting that error
'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'title' of 'list' as it is undefined.'.
what am i missing

Comment: What's inside `response.data`?

Comment: axios.get() should have a proper url like `get(http:localhost:5000/lists)`

Comment: when axios send get request, I get back my data in my console. but i cannot use the lists props in the List.jsx page

Comment: the data inside response.data are:     title: {type:String, required:true, unique: true},
    type: {type:String},
    genre: {type:String},
    content: {type:Array}.

Answer (score 0):

Since your useEffect() is not running synchronously it is going to run the lists.map before the setLists() ever gets called in the useEffect() function therefore you will have undefined for those values. You need to delay the lists.map until you have the data from axios. Try adding a check like i did below to make sure the list is not empty.

```
import './Home.scss'
import Navbar from '../../components/Navbar/Navbar'
import Featured from '../../components/Featured/Featured'
import List from '../../components/List/List'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from '../../axios'

function Home({ type }) {
 const [lists, setLists] = useState([]);
 const [genre, setGenre] = useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {
  const getRandomLists = async () =>{
   try {
     const response = await axios.get(
      `https://myapi.com/lists`,
      ,{
        headers: {
          token: "Bearer //my jwt token"
         },
        }
       );
      console.log(response)
      setLists(response.data)

    } catch (err) {
     console.log(err)
   }
};

 getRandomLists();
 }, [type, genre])

 return (
   <div className='home'>
     <Navbar />
     <Featured type={type}/>
      // Make sure you actually have data here
      {lists.length > 0 ? lists.map((list) => (
       <List list={list}/>
      )) : null}
  </div>
  )
  }

  export default Home
```

Comment: okay, But i have created an instance ok axios in a axios.js file do I still need to give a full url to axios.get each time because I will upload my project to a live server when I am done. I am currently using localhost.

Comment: i have the solution i am still getting the same error.

Comment: I received data from my data base i can see it in my console. but i cannot access it in the List.jsx page

Comment: Okay so you have the data, that's good. It is most likely cause you are not checking if lists has any length so it is mapping out the empty array and then you get an undefined error. You will either need to add the check above that I showed or do an async and await on the useEffect

Comment: I have updated my code with yours but if I try to use it in the List.jsx page i still get the error

Comment: in the List.jsx page, i call the property of the list like list.title. you can check the code of the List.jsx page i uploaded.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your assistance i found the error, it was a typo